# Need help at XSL transformation from one xml file to another one

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transformation

I need help at the following transformation. A part of the transformation is working but I can't find the bug why I get not only the matched values but also all other values of the xml file.

Here is my xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Config>
    <MwUri>xxx</MwUri>
    <Plant>
        <Name>2</Name>
        <Gate>
            <Name>2_Einfahrt</Name>
            <NotificationURI>yyy</NotificationURI>
            <Reader>
                <Name>2</Name>
                <Ports>
                    <Port>
                        <Type>INPUT</Type>
                        <Id>1</Id>
                        <TriggerType value="1" />
                        <OperationType>READ</OperationType>
                    </Port>
                    <Port>
                        <Type>INPUT</Type>
                        <Id>3</Id>
                        <TriggerType value="2" />
                        <OperationType>READ</OperationType>
                    </Port>
                    <Port>
                        <Type>OUTPUT</Type>
                        <Id>5</Id>
                        <TriggerType value="3" />
                        <OperationType>WRITE</OperationType>
                        <OutputDuration>1000</OutputDuration>
                        <DurationUnit>MS</DurationUnit>
                    </Port>
                </Ports>
            </Reader>
        </Gate>
    </Plant>
</Config>
```

and here the xslt-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="parameterName" />

    <xsl:template match="TriggerType[@value='1']">
        <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                    <opSpecs>
                        <opSpec>
                            <opType>
                                <xsl:value-of select="../OperationType" />
                            </opType>
                            <portSpec>
                                <id>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../Id" />
                                </id>
                                <reader>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../../../Name" />
                                </reader>
                                <type>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../Type" />
                                </type>
                            </portSpec>
                        </opSpec>
                    </opSpecs>
                </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
xxx

2

2_Einfahrt
yyy


2


INPUT
1
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

            <opSpecs>
                <opSpec>
                    <opType>READ</opType>
                    <portSpec>
                        <id>1</id>
                        <reader>2</reader>
                        <type>INPUT</type>
                    </portSpec>
                </opSpec>
            </opSpecs>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
READ


INPUT
3

READ


OUTPUT
5

WRITE
1000
MS
```

What I need is just this:

```
        <opSpecs>
            <opSpec>
                <opType>READ</opType>
                <portSpec>
                    <id>1</id>
                    <reader>2</reader>
                    <type>INPUT</type>
                </portSpec>
            </opSpec>
        </opSpecs>
</s:Body>
```

Can someone help me? :))))

Comment: oh, sorry. I need of course this as result:

Comment: <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

            <opSpecs>
                <opSpec>
                    <opType>READ</opType>
                    <portSpec>
                        <id>1</id>
                        <reader>2</reader>
                        <type>INPUT</type>
                    </portSpec>
                </opSpec>
            </opSpecs>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

Comment: You can edit your post and include this information, rather than posting it as a comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, by default, all text is sent to the output if you do not prevent that. In your original code, all text nodes are matched by the *default* template for text nodes.

So, add a template that matches `text()` and does nothing with those nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

This also removes all the whitespace, and your output will be one long string of XML. Therefore, add another top-level instruction that properly indents the resulting XML:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
```

and then, the result will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <opSpecs>
         <opSpec>
            <opType>READ</opType>
            <portSpec>
               <id>1</id>
               <reader>2</reader>
               <type>INPUT</type>
            </portSpec>
         </opSpec>
      </opSpecs>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hello Mathias, thanks for the fast reply :))) But in this case I will always get the values from the first port, right?! I need the possibility to search for the different TriggerTypes and fill the new xml (--> after transformation) with different values.

Comment: @hartman This does not change your transformation in any way, except that the superfluous text disappears. If you'd like to change your XML output, edit your question and show what exactly the output should be.

Comment: @ Mathias: It worked after I added these two lines to my xslt. Thanks a lot. You are the best!!!